# "Lining" vs "Padding"

Tags: word-usage

I was having a discussion with someone in regards to these two terms. I like to sew and I watch/read a lot of tutorials from which I have learned all sorts of terms and I was wondering if someone could explain if there is much difference between using "lining" and "padding".
I use lining when it's about clothes, such as dress. Let's say I want to make a satin dress and I choose another fabric as the *lining* (the one that is on the inside of the dress).
For *padding* however, I think it's more used when a bulkier material is used. I know of "padded envelopes", or "padded bras" for examples and I think even with furniture such as sofas, in regards to the interior structure, they could have a foam padding.

> To pad (often as adjective padded) Fill or cover (something) with a soft material in order to protect or shape it or to make it more comfortable.

That's one of the definitions that I have found which I understand and how I also define padding, that it involves a thicker material. Goose-down padded jacket for example, it would mean that it's a filling material, right?
  These terms might be similar but I would like to hear more opinions, because in my language we have one word for the notion of "lining" and I want to differentiate when I translate texts into English.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Padding adds volume, whereas lining does not.

Comment: Padding is the bulky material that invariably is contained behind a lining.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. 
Padding in this context is a bulky material used to "Pad" the article of clothing. As you said, shoulder pads, bras and such. Often times Padding is in between two layers of fabric. Can also be used to bulk out an item, such as a pillow or stuffed animal.
A lining is a secondary material used mostly to protect the skin or delicate fabric. Usually, this is a non-important fabric that is almost never seen.

Comment: I don't why the friend who I am explaining to does not want to go with "padding" and prefers to just go with "lining" even though in English we can make this distinction. I mean, even from a source where there are native English speakers around, my friend keeps doubting.
We had to translate the components of a sofa, like the fabrics, the materials of its structure and I for one still prefer to use lining when it's about a thin fabric, used in clothes and padding when it's something such as foam or wadding that you actually find inside a sofa.